# SQL Server - Loop records insert 100 at a time

Tags: sql-server, loops, insert

I have an INSERT query inside a stored procedure that creates a set of parcels monthly named "MONTHLY_SET".
Sometimes the set gets too big, I need to be able to continue run the same insert query, but rather than insert, for example, 5000 records in a single set named "MONTHLY SET", I need to end up with 5 sets of 1000 each named: "MONTHLY_SET1", "MONTHLY_SET2", "MONTHLY_SET3", "MONTHLY_SET4", "MONTHLY_SET5"

I do not know how this can be achieved, I am not familiar with the use of cursor, and loops in T-SQL, or if those are the only available options to do this.

Would it be possible to ask for some help to understand how can I split a shingle set into smaller sets?

The INSERT query that needs to be inside a loop, currently looks like:

```
DECLARE @SETSEQ AS INT;
SET @SETSEQ = (SELECT MAX(SET_SEQ_NBR) FROM SETDETAILS);

INSERT INTO SETDETAILS 
(   SERV_PROV_CODE
,   SET_SEQ_NBR
,   SET_ID
,   REC_DATE
,   REC_FUL_NAM
,   REC_STATUS
,   SOURCE_SEQ_NBR
,   L1_PARCEL_NBR
)
SELECT Top 10
    'STRING'
,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ParcelNumber ASC) + @SETSEQ
,   'MONTHLY_SET'
,   GETDATE()
,   'USR'
,   'A' 
,   '155'
,   ParcelNumber
FROM 
    dbo.Parcels
WHERE 
    Create = 1;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you *have* to do this in 5 separate `INSERT` statements? Why not 1, and number the set according? SQL Server can handle millions of rows in a single `INSERT` easily, so 5,000 would be trivial./

Comment: I could try that way, the think is that not all the times there will be 5,000 records, sometimes there might be less, sometimes more. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you need to cross-join 1000 rows against those five values

Comment: I kept researching, to try to learn how to do this, an option I found is called pagination, which I think means to break a large set of data into smaller ones, which is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The term "pagination" is typically used as a technique for applications to optimize the overall performance of retrieving and view large resultsets. That does not seem to be useful here. Unfortunately your actual goal is really clear. SQL Server can easily handle vastly more rows (than 5000) if the database is properly designed - as already noted. Perhaps one of the [ranking functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) might help here if you need to group rows during insert.